# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'mediapipe' has no attribute 'solutions'

Tags: python, opencv

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\app.py", line 3, in 
import mediapipe as mp
File "c:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\mediapipe.py", line 3, in 
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'mediapipe' has no attribute 'solutions' (most likely due to a circular import)

```
import cv2
import time
import mediapipe as mp
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("1.mp4")
pTime = 0
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mpFaceMesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
faceMesh = mpFaceMesh.FaceMesh(max_num_faces=2)
while True:
  success, img = cap.read()
  imgRGN = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  results = faceMesh.process(imgRGN)
  if results.multi_face_landmarks:
    for faceLms in results.multi_face_landmarks:
        mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img,faceLms, mpFaceMesh.FACE_CONNECTIONS)
  cTime = time.time()
  fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime )
  pTime = cTime
  cv2.putText(img, f'FPS:{int(fps)}',(20,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                3,(0,255,0),3 )
  cv2.imshow("Image", img)
  cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Don't use module name as your file name. Here I can see you have `c:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\mediapipe.py`. Rename it to another name.

Comment: `mediapipe` is a module name.

Comment: PS G:\AppPart14\src> & C:/Users/Ahmed/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\app.py", line 11, in <module>
    imgRGN = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
INFO: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.

Comment: This is another error. Is your first error gone now?

Comment: yes This is another error

Comment: You can write detailed description of error in another question as your error in this question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to utilize module name as your document name. Here I can see you have c:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\mediapipe.py. Rename it to another name
mediapipe is a module name